# Loop does not terminate when reading a password in C

Tags: c

When executing this code the loop does not terminates when entering enter key. I have tried using fflush(stdin);

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
    char password[55];

    printf("password:\n");
    int p=0;
    do{
        password[p]=getch();
        if(password[p]!='\n'){
            printf("*");
        }
        p++;
    }while(password[p-1]!='\n');
    fflush(stdin);
    password[p-1]='\0';
    printf("\n");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `fflush()` on input streams is undefined behaviour.

Comment: From where did you learn about `fflush(stdin);`?

Comment: @babon From MS of course! Is an MS 'extension', absolutely not compliant C. As `main()`...

Comment: `void main()` is also not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Windows.

Where end-of-line is `\r\n` instead of `\n`, so your `getch()` will give you `\r` (0x0d) instead of `\n` (0x0a) for the line end.

Replace `!= '\n'` with `!= '\r'` and you have a program that will work as expected... on Windows. (Which you are bound to by `#include <conio.h>` anyway.)

Note that `fflush( stdin );` is a Microsoft extension of the language and likewise non-portable. (The langauge standard considers `fflush()` on input streams *undefined behaviour*.)

And it is either `int main( void )` or `int main( int argc, char * argv[] )`. `void main()` is not legal C.

Answer (score 0):

The ENTER key is `'\r'`, not `'\n'`. To input a `'\n'` you can stroke CTRL-J.